# Custom attachment function not working in v5.4.2?

Tags: custom-post-types, functions, post-meta, attachments

I have a function that I re-use in a number of custom themes when required to fulfil a customers need. I understand this can be achieved now with repeaters in ACF Pro but as I had a working function, I chose to use this.

The problem I'm now facing is I'm really stuck with getting this to show on a custom post type within v5.4.2. I even installed the 'classic Editor' plugin to see if it was an issue with legacy meta fields but no joy...

The code of the function with comments is:

```
    //custom post type attachments for bikes.
add_filter( 'attachments_default_instance', '__return_false' ); // disable the default instance

function post_attachments( $attachments )
{
  $fields         = array(
    array(
      'name'      => 'title',                         // unique field name
      'type'      => 'text',                          // registered field type
      'label'     => __( 'Title', 'attachments' ),    // label to display
      'default'   => 'title',                         // default value upon selection
    ),
    array(
      'name'      => 'caption',                       // unique field name
      'type'      => 'textarea',                      // registered field type
      'label'     => __( 'Caption', 'attachments' ),  // label to display
      'default'   => 'caption',                       // default value upon selection
    ),
  );

  $args = array(
    // title of the meta box (string)
    'label'         => 'Bike Images',
    // all post types to utilize (string|array)
    'post_type'     => array( 'post', 'page', 'used' ),
    // meta box position (string) (normal, side or advanced)
    'position'      => 'normal',
    // meta box priority (string) (high, default, low, core)
    'priority'      => 'high',
    // allowed file type(s) (array) (image|video|text|audio|application)
    'filetype'      => null,  // no filetype limit
    // include a note within the meta box (string)
    'note'          => 'Attach files here!',
    // by default new Attachments will be appended to the list
    // but you can have then prepend if you set this to false
    'append'        => true,
    // text for 'Attach' button in meta box (string)
    'button_text'   => __( 'Attach Files', 'attachments' ),
    // text for modal 'Attach' button (string)
    'modal_text'    => __( 'Attach', 'attachments' ),
    // which tab should be the default in the modal (string) (browse|upload)
    'router'        => 'browse',
    // whether Attachments should set 'Uploaded to' (if not already set)
      'post_parent'   => false,
    // fields array
    'fields'        => $fields,
  );

  $attachments->register( 'post_attachments', $args );
}
add_action( 'attachments_register', 'post_attachments' );
```

I'm quite stuck with this so any tips would be much appreciated. I also need to serve the URL's of these image files back via the v2 API. Does this requirement make it even more pertinent to use a plgin such as ACF Pro?

I worry about using too much 3rd party plugins when building bespoke themes not intended to be re-sold etc.

Comment: I don't fully understand your use case, but there's no WP default action called `'attachments_register'`, so this code will never run, unless you're calling your own `do_action` for this somewhere else?

Answer (score 0):

it was completely my bad. I am using this plugin and I updated my functions.php file but the plugin wasn't activated although I thought it had been.

Extension is here & it works in 5.4.2 with Gutenberg blocks if anybody is intereested:

https://github.com/jchristopher/attachments